# Enforce structure of file with PLY

Tags: python, ply

I am trying to process input file with description of algorithm behavior. I am using python's PLY module for defining lexer and parser. I stumbled upon problem of defining grammar which will enforce user to correctly write this file.

**File**

```
# Beginning of the first section
STATES = INITIATOR, IDLE, DONE;
INIT = INITIATOR, IDLE;
TERM = DONE;
# End of first section

# Beginning of the second section
INITIATOR
    RANDOM
    begin
       SEND(x, NEIGHBORS);
       BECOME(DONE);
    end

IDLE
    RECEIVE(x)
    begin
        SEND(x, NEIGHBORS);
        BECOME(DONE);
    end
# End of second section
```

**Lexer**

```
import ply.lex as lex
from soda.helpers import prepare_file


class Lexer(object):
    keywords = (
        'INIT', 'TERM', 'STATES', 'REGISTERS',
        'begin', 'end',
        'SEND', 'BECOME'
    )

    tokens = keywords + (
        'NAME', 'EQUALS', 'COMMA', 'SEMICOLON',
        'LPAREN', 'RPAREN'
    )

    # Tokens

    t_EQUALS = r'='
    t_COMMA = r','
    t_SEMICOLON = r';'
    t_STATES = r'STATES'
    t_REGISTERS = r'REGISTERS'
    t_INIT = r'INIT'
    t_TERM = r'TERM'
    t_begin = r'begin'
    t_end = r'end'
    t_SEND = r'SEND'
    t_BECOME = r'BECOME'
    t_LPAREN = r'\('
    t_RPAREN = r'\)'

    # Ignored characters
    t_ignore = ' \t\n'

    def t_NAME(self, t):
        r'[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]*'
        if t.value in self.keywords:  # is this a keyword?
            t.type = t.value
        return t

    def t_error(self, t):
        print ("Illegal character {0} at line {1}".format(t.value[0], t.lineno))
        t.lexer.skip(1)

    def build(self, **kwargs):
        self._lexer = lex.lex(module=self, **kwargs)

    @prepare_file
    def lexical_analysis(self, file):
        print ("Started lexical analysis...")
        for line in file:
            try:
                lex_input = line
            except EOFError:
                break

            self._lexer.input(lex_input)
            while True:
                token = self._lexer.token()
                if not token:
                    break
                print ("  ", token)
```

**Parser**

```
import ply.yacc as yacc
from soda.helpers import prepare_file


class Parser(object):
    def p_algorithm(self, p):
        ''' algorithm : first_section second_section'''

    def p_first_section(self, p):
        ''' first_section : STATES EQUALS states_list SEMICOLON
                          | REGISTERS EQUALS register_list SEMICOLON
                          | INIT EQUALS init_list SEMICOLON
                          | TERM EQUALS term_list SEMICOLON'''

    def p_states_list(self, p):
        ''' states_list  : state_term
                         | states_list COMMA state_term'''

    def p_state_term(self, p):
        ''' state_term : NAME'''
        self.behavior.states.append(p[1])

    def p_register_list(self, p):
        ''' register_list : register_term
                          | register_list COMMA register_term'''

    def p_register_term(self, p):
        ''' register_term : NAME'''
        self.behavior.registers.append(p[1])

    def p_init_list(self, p):
        ''' init_list : init_term
                      | init_list COMMA init_term'''

    def p_init_term(self, p):
        ''' init_term : NAME'''
        self.behavior.init_states.append(p[1])

    def p_term_list(self, p):
        ''' term_list : term_term
                      | term_list COMMA term_term'''

    def p_term_term(self, p):
        ''' term_term : NAME'''
        self.behavior.term_states.append(p[1])

    def p_second_section(self, p):
        ''' second_section : NAME begin commands end'''

    def p_error(self, p):
        print("Syntax error in input! -> {}".format(p))

    def build(self, lexer, behavior):
        self.lexer = lexer
        self.behavior = behavior
        self.tokens = lexer.tokens
        self._parser = yacc.yacc(module=self)

    @prepare_file
    def parsing(self, file):
        for line in file:
            try:
                parser_input = line
                print (line)
            except EOFError:
                break

        self._parser.parse(parser_input, lexer=self.lexer._lexer)
```

Parsing results in syntax error and I am not sure how to define rules to enforce the consistency of file with algorithm behavior. **first_section** is parsed ok and problem is **second_section**. My solution defines that **algorithm : first_section second_section** and it is not working. I tried to define it like **algorithm: first_section | second_section** and it works good but this rule states that first and second section can be switched in file.

So my question is how to enforce it with rules so user will keep the input file consistent.

**Error output**

```
enter STATES = INITIATOR, IDLE, DONE;

Syntax error in input! -> None
INIT = INITIATOR, IDLE;

Syntax error in input! -> None
TERM = DONE;

Syntax error in input! -> None
INITIATOR

Syntax error in input! -> LexToken(NAME,'INITIATOR',1,0)
begin
Syntax error in input! -> LexToken(begin,'begin',1,0)
```

Program just states there is error in syntax. Problem is not with lexical analysis but with defined grammar. I can define it in such way that input is accepted but for example user would be able to switch `first_section` with `second_section`.

**Edit**

I think it is not clear from this question what I want to achieve or my problem so I voted to close it. I came up with idea how to better state what I am looking for so I want to raise new question.

Comment: What error message do you get? Could you refine your question to be a minimal working example?

Comment: (Changing incorrect answer to comment): the pattern variables corresponding to keywords (from `t_STATES` to `t_BECOME`) will never succeed because `t_NAME` will be tried first. However, Ply will still try to match them for any position in the input which has not been matched by `t_NAME`, which is quite inefficient. Removing the variables will make your code easier to read, more maintainable, and somewhat faster.

Comment: @rici I get what you are saying but it works correctly. `STATES` in file is recognized as `t_STATES`. Definition of `t_NAME` is checking whether processed string is not a keyword. Or am I wrong ?

Comment: @M.Puk: the string `STATES` is recognized as the token `STATES` because  of the code in the function `t_NAME`: `if t.value in self.keywords: t.type = t.value`. That sets the token type because `t.value` is in `self.keywords`. Because `t_NAME` handles the token, the pattern ìn `t_STATES` will never succeed.

Comment: @rici Ok I get it now. I thought that it needs to be there. I will get rid of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oups! Your grammar parses the file line by line, which is at least uncommon and does not allow to control the ordering of lines. IMHO, you should parse the file as a whole. The trick is to pass the parser a `tokenfunc` function that will feed the lexer with one line at a time, and declare each section to be composed of lines:

```
class Parser(object):
    def p_algorithm(self, p):
        ''' algorithm : first_section second_section'''

    def p_first_section(self, p):
        ''' first_section : first_section_line
                          | first_section_line first_section'''

    def p_first_section_line(self, p):
        ''' first_section_line : STATES EQUALS states_list SEMICOLON
                          | REGISTERS EQUALS register_list SEMICOLON
                          | INIT EQUALS init_list SEMICOLON
                          | TERM EQUALS term_list SEMICOLON'''

    ...
    # same for second section...

    @prepare_file
    def parsing(self, file):
        def get_token():
            'a tokenizer that automatically feeds the lexer with the next line'
            while True:
                tok = self.lexer._lexer.token()
                if tok is not None: return tok
                try:
                    line = next(file)
                    self.lexer._lexer.input(line)
                except StopIteration:
                    return None

        self._parser.parse("", lexer=self.lexer._lexer, tokenfunc = get_token)
```

Comment: Exactly. I found out that parsing line by line is problem but I did not know how to solve it. I was working on it now and I just added more semicolons to file and started to read lines and concatenating them unless semicolon appeared so for example two lines were concatenated into one and parsed.

Comment: @M.Puk It is up to you to know whether you want to accept line breaks anywhere. As you lexer ignores newline and tabs, I assumed that lines could be folded, and that indentation was also ignored.

Comment: I will try your idea. I do not want user to enter semicolons everywhere. And yes it should ignore all whitespace characters. My problem was just that I wanted to define rule for example 'state_behavior : NAME begin commands end' so user would write file correctly.

Comment: I am trying to understand grammar you wrote. I get the whole idea but shouldn't `first_section` in `def p_first_section_line` be `first_section_line`?
Also I get that `first_section` can be mode of more lines but what should be definition of `first_section_lines`?

Comment: Yes but what about definition for `first_section_lines`? Shouldn't instead of it be `first_section`?

Comment: @M.Puk: Yes it should... Fixed (hoping no other stupid mistakes left...)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it and hope it will work correctly. This is just part of my project.